# How to flush output of dlmwrite in Octave

Tags: io, octave

`dlmwrite` command writes to a file, but without last few hundreds bytes. How can i flush these bytes. Seems i can't use `fflush` as i don't have file id. My Octave version is 4.2.1

EDIT: I conducted small experiment:

```
>> A=[1 1];
>> dlmwrite('A',A); % after this line you will have an empty file
>> exit             % after this line the file will contain "1,1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've found a bug in GNU Octave in dlmwrite if the filename is only one char long. Have a look at dlmwrite.m around line 197

```
...
if (! isscalar (file))
  fclose (fid);
endif
...
```

This code snippet tries to check if file is a filename or a fid (see alternative calling methods on dlmwrite). Obviously this check fails if the filename is only one byte long and is thus a scalar.

Please confirm that all works as expected if you use filenames with more than one char.

EDIT:

- [Bugreport on Savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?52679)
- [Bugfix on the stable branch](http://hg.octave.org/octave/rev/11d7cd4ece50)

Comment: Yap, it works fine with longer names. [The bug report.](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?52679) Thanks!